# Creating FairPlay Streaming (FPS) streams without using mediafilesegmenter

Tags: ffmpeg, drm, fairplay

In the past, I have done encrypted HLS using a combination of ffmpeg and openssl, but not FPS (yet).

I'm sure this is possible, but I haven't found a way to do it yet and I'm wondering if anyone has done it and would be willing to share how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a tool that does this fantastically: bento4

https://www.bento4.com/

The docs are top-notch and the output is perfect.